# How to grab MetaMask Rinkeby address

Tags: web3js, metamask

In my web3 how do I grab the Rinkeby wallet address from MetaMask? How do I request ether from this address?

Answer (score 1):

The below can get the Accounts from metamask. Check web3 wiki for more details.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
          console.log("Load Metamask");
        }
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
            //your code goes here
            }); });
```